# SSL handshake error

Tags: php, сокет, websocket, ssl, workerman

Есть сокет сервер на PHP (библиотека workerman). И периодически в консоли появляется ошибка, когда пользователь подключается к серверу:
SSL handshake error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Узнал, что чаще всего это люди, сидящие через VPN.
Как эту ошибку устранить, если вообще возможно?